# Changing not in clause to inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I convert the following query to inner join and avoid using distinct to optimise performance.

```
select distinct(GroupId) 
from   BatchQuotaIndividualQuotas 
where  BatchQuotaCommonSettingsID = 58 
       and 
       GroupId not in 
       (
           select distinct(groupid) 
           from   BatchQuotaIndividualQuotas 
           where  BatchQuotaCommonSettingsID = 58 
                  and ObjectiveFunctionTotalResultID is null 
       )
```

GroupId is not primary key. There are multiple rows corresponding to a single GroupId. I want to select the GroupIds for which none of the ObjectiveFunctionTotalResultID is null. –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you remove distinct from the where clause, your query will run faster.

Here are 2 better ways of writing it

count(ObjectiveFunctionTotalResultID) will count not null values

```
SELECT GroupId
FROM   BatchQuotaIndividualQuotas 
WHERE  BatchQuotaCommonSettingsID = 58 
GROUP BY GroupId
HAVING count(ObjectiveFunctionTotalResultID) = count(*)
```

or:

EXCEPT will include distinct

```
SELECT GroupId
FROM   BatchQuotaIndividualQuotas 
WHERE  BatchQuotaCommonSettingsID = 58 
EXCEPT
SELECT GroupId
FROM   BatchQuotaIndividualQuotas 
WHERE  BatchQuotaCommonSettingsID = 58 
AND ObjectiveFunctionTotalResultID is null
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, distinct is not a function, but a modifier of the select statement. You select a distinct combination of field values rather than a distinct single field. The parentheses will actually call a syntax error if you have more fields. So it's not

```
select
  distinct(groupid)
```

but

```
select distinct
  groupid
```

Secondly, you don't need the inner distinct at all. Duplicates may exist in an `in` list, and the dbms is likely to optimize this for you already. By adding `distinct` yourself in the inner query, you are actively preventing the optimizer to do its job.

Thirdly, you will still need `distinct` on the outer query if you want to have distinct group ids. Inner join doesn't change that. Besides, since you want to have records that must *not* match, an inner join wouldn't do the trick. A left join could do it, but if I interpret your query correctly, you could just write it as:

```
select distinct
  GroupId
from 
  BatchQuotaIndividualQuotas 
where 
  BatchQuotaCommonSettingsID = 58 and 
  ObjectiveFunctionTotalResultID is not null
```

You *could* change it to `group by` like I do below, but the effect is the same. Group by just creates groups, and has to remove duplicates as well. Group by is mostly used for aggregations. I'm not sure about the inner workings, but group by is theoretically a harder process, because the database needs to create actual groups for these aggregations, instead of just filtering out duplicates. Probably this will be optimized as well, so in the end, the query below will perform and behave the same as the one above.

```
select
  GroupId
from 
  BatchQuotaIndividualQuotas 
where 
  BatchQuotaCommonSettingsID = 58 and 
  ObjectiveFunctionTotalResultID is not null
group by
  GroupId
```

Comment: your answer is not correct, for the same reasons posted under Alex's answer

Comment: Showing the importance of adding information like that (table structure, keys) to the question. :) I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Had a look at it, and you can solve it with a `left join`, which I already briefly mentioned before my -though to be- answer query. But @Dan already worked out that solution in his answer, so you can pick his. :)

Comment: except i posted 2 better answers

Comment: not a matter of opinion, a matter of performance and readability. This is not philosophy

Comment: @t-clausen.dk You even said 'To my opinion..' in your answer, and it's true, especially for readability. If you want to claim performance, add a benchmark to your answer. But this wasn't about you in the first place. I just said I suggested Dan's answer because he implemented the idea I also had. Sorry if I offended you by not giving you a pat on the shoulder as well, but don't be a dick about it.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve a similar result using a `LEFT JOIN` and then setting the join result to `NULL`.

```
select distinct GroupId
from   BatchQuotaIndividualQuotas A
left join BatchQuotaIndividualQuotas B ON B.ObjectiveFunctionTotalResultID IS NULL 
                                      AND B.GroupId = A.GroupId
                                      AND B.BatchQuotaCommonSettingsID = 58
where  A.BatchQuotaCommonSettingsID = 58
   AND B.GroupId IS NULL
```

You can also achieve the same result with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`, although I doubt this approach would be faster.

```
select GroupId
from   BatchQuotaIndividualQuotas 
where  BatchQuotaCommonSettingsID = 58
group by GroupId
having SUM(CASE WHEN ObjectiveFunctionTotalResultID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this please?

```
select GroupId
from   BatchQuotaIndividualQuotas 
where  BatchQuotaCommonSettingsID = 58 
and ObjectiveFunctionTotalResultID  IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY GroupId
```

Same query (If I am correct) with some revised flow. Instead of filtering out the IDs by a subquery, it does it in place.

Comment: This wont work correctly because GroupId is not primary key. There are multiple rows corresponding to a single GroupId. I want to select the GroupIds for which none of the ObjectiveFunctionTotalResultID  is null.